# How to run an animated plot inline with Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python-3.x, animation, jupyter-lab

Running my animated plot in a jupyter notebook is OK. Now trying the same code in Jupyter Lab does not work. I've read a lot of similar situations, tried every solution given, but my plot stays static. No animation running.

This is my extension list, installed and enabled ('jupyter lab build'):

```
$ jupyter labextension list
JupyterLab v0.35.4
Known labextensions:
   app dir: /home/teleuff/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v0.38.1  enabled  OK
        @jupyterlab/plotly-extension v1.0.0  enabled  OK
        jupyter-matplotlib v0.3.0  enabled  OK
        plotlywidget v1.1.0  enabled  OK
```

%matplotlib inline does not raise JavaScript error, but my plot is not animated.

%matplotlib widget and %pylab inline also have the same effect, only difference is the output line:

```
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find and click the little shield on the table frame at the bottom of the screen.  Is this shield icon displaying a check mark inside the shield?  Hover the mouse above the shield, does the shield then display a message:

{ Active Cell Trusted: x of y shields trusted }

It's likely there is no check mark inside the shield.  The reason is the Jupyter extension is designed to be locked down.

Review the Jupyter-notebook security page: [Jupyter-notebook](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html)

Overview from the security page:

- Untrusted HTML is always sanitized
- Untrusted JavaScript is never executed
- Html and JavaScript in Markdown cells are never trusted
- Outputs generated by the user are trusted
- Any other HTML or JavaScript (in Markdown cells, output generated by       owners) is never trusted

The bottom line and central question of trust is: Did the current user do this?  I've found Jupyter Lab security settings make bullet-number 3 the overriding rule.